# POST request results is HTTP 415 error through JMeter proxy

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, jmeter

I try to implement a load test in jmeter for a web service written in java (Spring MVC+Hibernate). The server is RESTFull and a client (in angularjs) communicates with server.

I want to dump HTTP request with jmeter HTTP Request recorder the same as [a tutorial on jmeter user guides](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html).

The problem is that I keep on getting a 415 Http error while using jmeter as proxy on web browser. So the webpage is faced with an error while trying to post data and fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTTP Status Code 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) stands for **Unsupported Media Type**, it means that [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header is either incorrect or missing.

JMeter shouldn't be removing this header so my expectation is that either there is a problem with your application or with JMeter itself.

Try recording your test scenario using i.e. [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) and if it will be successful - please raise a ticket in [JMeter Bugzilla](http://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html)

Comment: Thanks, this is jmeter bug.